# Attach a webform into faq module content

Tags: 7

I'm looking for a FAQ module where users can answer the "Did you find this answer useful? Yes-No" after reading help and I need a page where operators can check all responses.

Any idea?

Comment: Please don't edit the question while it gets answers.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.drupal.org/project/faq

> The Frequently Asked Questions (faq) module allows users, with
>   appropriate permissions, to create question and answer pairs which
>   they want displayed on the 'faq' page. The 'faq' page is automatically
>   generated from the FAQ nodes configured. Basic Views layouts are also
>   provided and can be customised via the Views UI (rather than via the
>   module settings page)

.